# How does Android display missing glyphs?

Tags: android, fonts

I noticed U+266D (music flat ♭) displays better on my galaxy phone versus my galaxy tablet. It seems that on both devices the character is not part of any of the installed fonts... So where does the glyph come from? On my tablet, it seems like it's using a raster image: it's grey, "embossed" looking and doesn't change colour with font colour. It looks exactly the same with every installed font, suggesting it's not actually part of the font, and online "font explorer" tools suggest the same. I'm just wondering the name of this mechanism so I can do more research?

Comment: Specific device models and OS versions along with where encountered would be useful. Note that [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=font) may be more appropriate. If for your own app, be aware of [Internationalization](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/internationalization?hl=en) and [Emoji support](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/emoji2) which may affect unicode font/set/char availability.

Comment: Which models would you have an answer for?

Comment: More for any reader and perhaps images to help understand what you are seeing. Again this may be a font issue OR app issue but as written unclear what you are asking. If the glyph is missing, you should get a tofu or box with an X (as referenced in my links). If you asking about how Android renders under the hood, see: https://medium.com/@romainguy/androids-font-renderer-c368bbde87d9 But by not mentioning the OS version on each, readers can only speculate.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a read. Yeah that's what I would've expected: box with X. But instead both galaxy devices get a glyph from "somewhere" other than the font file... I'm basing that on the fact they both use the same glyph for all fonts, they both have the same fonts installed, and both devices are showing a different glyph... I'm kinda fishing for an answer like "oh yeah that's the 'use this if glyph not available' feature...". I'll try to get some screenshots when I'm back home